# Difference between "findAll" and "find_all" in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml-parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse an HTML file with Python, and the module I am using is BeautifulSoup.

It is said that the function `find_all` is the same as `findAll`. I've tried both of them, but I believe they are different:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import *
site = "http://share.dmhy.org/topics/list?keyword=TARI+TARI+team_id%3A407"

rqstr = urllib2.Request(site)
rq = urllib2.urlopen(rqstr)
fchData = rq.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(fchData)

t = soup.findAll('tr')
```

Can anyone tell me the difference?

Comment: which version of beautifulsoup are you using? If you're supposed to use BS4, then import should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4

Comment: What is the difference? I mean, you said you used both and you saw a difference. Could you post some output that shows the different behaviour? Or are you asking why there are two methods that does the same thing? In that case Martijn Pieters is correct.

Comment: find_all : it couldn't find the module
findAll : it found several parts of html code.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In BeautifulSoup version 4, the methods are exactly the same; the mixed-case versions (`findAll`, `findAllNext`, `nextSibling`, etc.) have all been renamed to conform to the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but the *old* names are still available to make porting easier. See [Method Names](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) for a full list.

In new code, you should use the lowercase versions, so `find_all`, etc.

In your example however, you are using BeautifulSoup *version 3* (discontinued since March 2012, *don't* use it if you can help it), where only `findAll()` is available. Unknown attribute names (such as `.find_all`, which only is available in BeautifulSoup 4) are treated as if you are searching for a tag by that name. There is no `<find_all>` tag in your document, so `None` is returned for that.

Answer (score 11):

from the source code of BeautifulSoup:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1260

```
def find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None,
                 limit=None, **kwargs):
# ...
# ...

findAll = find_all       # BS3
findChildren = find_all  # BS2
```