# p tag with/without class and strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and I'm trying to understand BeautifulSoup.

I did this code it works but not the way I want:

```
for abc in soup.findAll(['p',{'a':re.compile('href="/download/*')}]):
    value=abc.text
    print value
```

The page multiple "blocks" as this one:

```
<div class="">
  <div class="ABC">
    <p>
      <a href="/download/1234/abcde/fghij">String1</a>
    </p>
    <p class="data">
      String2 <a href="/user/4649/abc">String3</a> String2 
    </p>
  </div>
  <img src="/img/abc.png" alt="String4" title="String5" />
</div>
```

I want to read all this "blocks" and convert to a dictionary(?):
`[Link'/download/1234/abcde/fghij', Name'String1', User'String3', alt'String4, title'String5']`

With this I can search for Name and get the Link

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for outer in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": ""}):
    a = outer.find("a")
    img = outer.find("img")
    entry = { "Link": a.get("href")
            , "Name": a.text
            , "User": outer.find("p", "data").find("a").text
            , "alt": img.get("alt")
            , "title": img.get("title")
            }
    print entry
```

This retrieves the things that you want and puts them in a dictionary.

Comment: thanks! worked! I didn't know I could do two consecutive finds. The correct is findAll and not find_all.

Comment: `find_all` works for newer versions of the soup, whereas `findAll` works in newer and previous, but maybe not in the future ones.  Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/beautifulsoup-findall-find-all).