# Python None check seems to fail using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I have looked at similar posts, which come close to my case, but my result nonetheless seems unexpected.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(<html page of interest>)
if (soup.find_all("td", attrs= {"class": "FilterElement"}, text= re.compile("HERE IS TEXT I AM LOOKING FOR")) is None):
    print('There was no entry')
else:
    print(soup.find("td", attrs= {"class": "FilterElement"}, text= re.compile("HERE IS THE TEXT I AM LOOKING FOR")))
```

I obviously filtered out the actual HTML page, as well as the text in the regular expression.  The rest is exactly as written.  I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/appa/src/workspace/web_forms/WebForms/src/root/queryForms.py", line 51, in <module>
    LoopThroughDays(form, id, trailer)
  File "/Users/appa/src/workspace/web_forms/WebForms/src/root/queryForms.py", line 33, in LoopThroughDays
    if (soup.find_all("td", attrs= {"class": "FilterElement"}, text= re.compile("HERE IS THE TEXT I AM LOOKING FOR")) is None):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I understand that the text will sometimes be missing.  But I thought that the way I have set up the `if` statement was precisely able to capture when it is missing, and therefore a `NoneType`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: don't your import should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`? as `BeautifulSoup4` is in `bs4` module

Comment: @salmanwahed Yes, I saw other sites referring to bs4, but when I installed (via easy_install), the base library was simply BeautifulSoup.  I use it without a problem in other areas, so I suspect this is another (newer?) version of BeautifulSoup?  Not sure why the difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's just a typo. It should be `soup.findAll` not `soup.find_all`. I tried running it, and it works with the correction. So the full program should be:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(<html page of interest>)
if (soup.findAll("td", attrs= {"class": "FilterElement"}, text= re.compile("HERE IS TEXT I AM LOOKING FOR")) is None):
    print('There was no entry')
else:
    print(soup.find("td", attrs= {"class": "FilterElement"}, text= re.compile("HERE IS THE TEXT I AM LOOKING FOR")))<html page of interest>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I will not be able to check until later in the evening, but I will give an "accepted" check mark at that point.

Comment: `find_all` is correct in version 4+. findAll will still work, but find_all is more pythonic: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/beautifulsoup-findall-find-all