# Obtaining column from wikipedia table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
source_code = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift_discography')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text)
tables = soup.find_all("table")
```

I'm trying to get a list of song names from the table "List of Singles" at [Taylor Swift's discography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift_discography)

The table has no unique class or id. The only unique thing I can think of is the caption tag around "List of singles..."

> List of singles as main artist, with selected chart positions, sales figures and certifications

I tried:

```
table = soup.find_all("caption")
```

but it returns nothing, i'm assuming that caption is not a recognized tag in bs4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually nothing to do with `findAll()` and `find_all()`. `findAll()` was used in `BeautifulSoup3` and was left in `BeautifulSoup4` *for compatibility reasons*, quote from the `bs4`'s source code:

```
def find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None,
             limit=None, **kwargs):
    generator = self.descendants
    if not recursive:
        generator = self.children
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)

findAll = find_all       # BS3
```

---

And, there is a nicer way to get the list of singles, relying on the `span` element with `id="Singles"` that indicates the start of `Singles` paragraph. Then, use the [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get the first table after the `span` tag's parent. Then, get all `th` elements with `scope="row"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source_code = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift_discography')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content)

table = soup.find('span', id='Singles').parent.find_next_sibling('table')
for single in table.find_all('th', scope='row'):
    print(single.text)
```

Prints:

```
"Tim McGraw"
"Teardrops on My Guitar"
"Our Song"
"Picture to Burn"
"Should've Said No"
"Change"
"Love Story"
"White Horse"
"You Belong with Me"
"Fifteen"
"Fearless"
"Today Was a Fairytale"
"Mine"
"Back to December"
"Mean"
"The Story of Us"
"Sparks Fly"
"Ours"
"Safe & Sound"
(featuring The Civil Wars)
"Long Live"
(featuring Paula Fernandes)
"Eyes Open"
"We Are Never Ever Getting Back Together"
"Ronan"
"Begin Again"
"I Knew You Were Trouble"
"22"
"Highway Don't Care"
(with Tim McGraw)
"Red"
"Everything Has Changed"
(featuring Ed Sheeran)
"Sweeter Than Fiction"
"The Last Time"
(featuring Gary Lightbody)
"Shake It Off"
"Blank Space"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example that solves the "Taylor Swift problem". First look for the caption that contains the text "List of singles" and move to the parent object". Next iterate over the items that have the text you are looking for:

```
for caption in soup.findAll("caption"):
    if "List of singles" in caption.text:      
        break

table = caption.parent
for item in table.findAll("th", {"scope":"row"}):
    print item.text
```

This gives:

```
"Tim McGraw"
"Teardrops on My Guitar"
"Our Song"
"Picture to Burn"
"Should've Said No"
"Change"
"Love Story"
"White Horse"
"You Belong with Me"
"Fifteen"
"Fearless"
"Today Was a Fairytale"
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that findAll and find_all did the same thing because of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/beautifulsoup-findall-find-all

Comment: @user2985522 I guess it depends on the version you are using: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4. If you are using the older BeautifulSoup it is `find_all`, but if you are using bs4 (and you should be) it is `findAll`.

Comment: @Hooked: isn't that backwards?  I was pretty sure that `findAll` was the older one.

Comment: @DSM, opps that is correct. I'll update my answer accordingly.