# convert html table to csv in python

Tags: python, selenium, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table from a dynamic page. After the following code (requires selenium), I manage to get the contents of the `<table>` elements.

I'd like to convert this table into a csv and I have tried 2 things, but both fail:

- `pandas.read_html` returns an error saying I don't have html5lib installed, but I do and in fact I can import it without problems.
- `soup.find_all('tr')` returns an error `'NoneType' object is not callable` after I run `soup = BeautifulSoup(tablehtml)`

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

main_url = "http://data.stats.gov.cn/english/easyquery.htm?cn=E0101"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(main_url)
time.sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Industry").click()
time.sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Main Economic Indicat").click()
time.sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_id("mySelect_sj").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("dtText").send_keys("last72")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("dtTextBtn").click()
time.sleep(2)
table=driver.find_element_by_id("table_main")
tablehtml= table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: what is the ouput of `tablehtml` ?

Comment: it's too long to paste. It starts like this: <thead><tr class="tr-title"><th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Indicators</strong><span class="" code="zb"></span></th><th class=""><strong>Oct 2015</strong><span class="" code="201510"></span></th><th class=""><strong>Sep 2015</strong><span class="" code="201509"></span></th><th class=""><strong>Aug 2015</strong><span class="" code="201508"></span></th><th class=""><strong>Jul 2011...
You can get the full version by running the code (you may need to pip install selenium)

Comment: I tested  your code with `selenium` and `bs4` and have got no issues. Somehow your  soup object is returned  as None.

Comment: You mean that you are able to use find_all() on my soup object?

Comment: yes. All I can recommend is check 'tablehtml' as well as 'soup' before you call anything on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without access to the table you're actually trying to scrape, I used this example:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Header1</td>
    <td>Header2</td>
    <td>Header3</td>
</tr>
</thead>  
<tr>
    <td>Row 11</td>
    <td>Row 12</td>
    <td>Row 13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 21</td>
    <td>Row 22</td>
    <td>Row 23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 31</td>
    <td>Row 32</td>
    <td>Row 33</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and scraped it using:

```
from bs4 import BEautifulSoup as BS
content = #contents of that table
soup = BS(content, 'html5lib')
rows = [tr.findAll('td') for tr in soup.findAll('tr')]
```

This *rows* object is a list of lists:

```
[
    [<td>Header1</td>, <td>Header2</td>, <td>Header3</td>],
    [<td>Row 11</td>, <td>Row 12</td>, <td>Row 13</td>],
    [<td>Row 21</td>, <td>Row 22</td>, <td>Row 23</td>],
    [<td>Row 31</td>, <td>Row 32</td>, <td>Row 33</td>]
]
```

...and you can write it to a file:

```
for it in rows:
with open('result.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write(", ".join(str(e).replace('<td>','').replace('</td>','') for e in it) + '\n')
```

which looks like this:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
Row 11, Row 12, Row 13
Row 21, Row 22, Row 23
Row 31, Row 32, Row 33
```

Comment: Thanks but like I mention, beautifusoupl returns a nonetype in my case and find_all does not work. Also the table can be accessed by simply running the code.

Comment: I was giving you a working example; BeautifulSoup does work, all you have to do is pay attention to its methods. Did you even try to run the example code I provided? You called "find_all" and it errored because   the method I used is "findAll". 
Please don't ask people to install selenium and run your script to get the table you need help with. Cheers

Comment: I had read that findAll and find_all are exacly the same (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/beautifulsoup-findall-find-all) but apparently, that is the case for "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup", not for "from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup", which is what I used. So you were right, sorry.

Answer (score 13):

Using the `csv` module and `selenium` selectors would probably be more convenient here:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com/")
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tableid")
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
```