# How to extract link from <a> inside the <h2 class=section-heading>:BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a link which is written like this:

```
<h2 class="section-heading">
    <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/pages/arts/index.html">Arts »</a>
</h2>
```

my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

def get_data():
    url='http://www.nytimes.com/'
    s_code=requests.get(url)
    plain_text = s_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    head_links=soup.findAll('h2', {'class':'section-heading'})

    for n in head_links :
       a = n.find('a')
       print a
       print n.get['href'] 
       #print a['href']
       #print n.get('href')
       #headings=n.text
       #links = n.get('href')
       #print headings, links

get_data()
```

the like "print a" simply prints out the whole `<a>` line inside the `<h2 class=section-heading>` i.e.

```
<a href="http://www.nytimes.com/pages/world/index.html">World »</a>
```

but when I execute "print n.get['href']", it throws me an error;

```
print n.get['href'] 
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help

I couldn't find some similar case question here, my issue is a bit unique here, I am trying to extract a link that is inside a specific class names section-headings.

Comment: Also, I think you mean to do `a.get('href')` and not `n.get`

Comment: @cricket_007 that duplicate question does not answer this exact error, though it is useful; and it is also for an earlier version of the library.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I was addressing the end-goal of the question, not the error, but yes I see what you're saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you want to fetch the `href` of the `a` element, thus you should be accessing `a` not `n` on that line. Secondly, it should be either

```
a.get('href')
```

**or**

```
a['href']
```

The latter form throws if no such attribute is found, whereas the former would return `None`, like the usual dictionary/mapping interface. As `.get` is a method, it should be called (`.get(...)`); indexing/element access wouldn't work for it (`.get[...]`), which is what this question is about.

---

Notice, that `find` might as well fail there, returning `None`, perhaps you wanted to iterate over `n.find_all('a', href=True)`:

```
for n in head_links:
   for a in n.find_all('a', href=True):
       print(a['href'])
```

---

Even easier than using `find_all` is to use the `select` method which takes a CSS selector. Here with a single operation we only get those `<a>` elements with `href` attribute that are inside a `<h2 class="section-heading">` as easily as with JQuery.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
for a in soup.select('h2.section-heading a[href]'):
    print(a['href'])
```

(Also, please use the [lower-case method names in any new code that you write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339416/918959)).

Comment: yes i've tried that aswell. If you look at those commented line in my code "links = n.get('href')", by doing this way, it returns me 'None' in all for loop iteration... 0.o ! and n['href'] throws me an error ' return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href' '

Comment: @AnumSheraz read my updated answer carefully

Comment: Thank you Antti, that helped (y)