# During webscraping I am getting the following error "invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 11)" in python 3.4.4 where print commad is written

Tags: python, syntax

I am writing this code to web scrape but I am continuously getting this error invalid syntax on the line "print(post)".

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
url_base="https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw="
requests="ps4"
url_separator="&_sacat=0&_pgn="
page_num="1"
url=url_base + requests + url_separator + page_num 
html= urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = b(html,'html.parser')
for post in soup.find_All("li",{"class":"s-item"}):
print(post)
```

I am using python 3.4.4. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `find_All` should be `find_all`; also your indentation as posted is wrong.

Comment: I have changed to find_all but still having the same error.. What do you mean by indentation?

Comment: Indentation is part of the Python syntax. It is basically the first thing you learn in every Python course.

Comment: E.g. [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php).

Comment: I have tried to fix the indentations but the error still persists, can it be the fault of my python version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix [indentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments#indentation) of the `print(post)` line and [use `find_all` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/beautifulsoup-findall-find-all):

```py
for post in soup.find_all("li",{"class":"s-item"}):
  print(post)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I have like wasted so much time on that and thanks for rescuing me... :')