# Beautiful Soup Scraper- BBall Reference

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have followed a video and an article(while trying to learn BS4). Both scrape similarly and I keep getting this error either way:

headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findALl('th')]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022_per_game.html"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findALl('th')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you have a typo with `.findALl()` when you wanted to use `.findAll()`. However, I like to use `.find_all()` instead.

Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/difference-between-findall-and-find-all-in-beautifulsoup)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen    

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022_per_game.html"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]

# Could use .find_all()
# headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.find_all('tr', limit=2)[0].find_all('th')]
```

**Output:**

```
print(headers)
['Rk', 'Player', 'Pos', 'Age', 'Tm', 'G', 'GS', 'MP', 'FG', 'FGA', 'FG%', '3P', '3PA', '3P%', '2P', '2PA', '2P%', 'eFG%', 'FT', 'FTA', 'FT%', 'ORB', 'DRB', 'TRB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF', 'PTS']
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was using requests the first go but switched it up when trying to solve the error.