# Webscraping with BS4 NoneType object has no attribute find

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm not sure why my code isn't working. I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

root_url = "https://urj.org/urj-congregations?congregation=&distance_address_field=&distance_num_miles=5.0&worship_services=All&community=All&urj_camp_affiliations=All&page=0"
html = requests.get(root_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

paging = soup.find("nav",{"aria-label":"pagination-heading-3"}).find("li",{"class":"page-item"}).find_all("a")
start_page = paging[1].text
last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text


outfile = open('congregationlookup.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "Address", "Phone"])


pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
for page in pages:
    url = 'https://urj.org/urj-congregations?congregation=&distance_address_field=&distance_num_miles=5.0&worship_services=All&community=All&urj_camp_affiliations=All&page=%s' %(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    #print(soup.prettify())
    print ('Processing page: %s' %(page))

    name_list = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"views-field views-field-congregation"})
    for element in name_list:
        name = element.find('h3').text
        address = element.find('field-content mb-2').text.strip()
        phone = element.find("i",{"class":"fa fa-phone mr-1"}).text.strip()

        writer.writerow([name, address, phone])

outfile.close()
print ('Done')
```

I'm trying to scrape the name, address, and phone number from the URJ Congregations website.

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of `find()` calls... which one is throwing the error? In any case, it's likely that a previous find has returned `None` because the thing you're searching for wasn't found.

Comment: @kindall paging = soup.find("div",{"Class":"pagination-heading-3"}).find("li",{"class":"page-item"}).find_all("a") is throwing the error.

Comment: There is a typo in your find statement. Actual value of `arial-label` attribute is `<nav aria-label="pagination-heading--3">` (note that there are 2 dashes not 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final code

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# root_url = "https://urj.org/urj-congregations?congregation=&distance_address_field=&distance_num_miles=5.0&worship_services=All&community=All&urj_camp_affiliations=All&page=0"
# html = requests.get(root_url)
# soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
# paging = soup.find("nav", {"aria-label": "pagination-heading--3"}).find("ul", {"class": "pagination"}).find_all("a")
# start_page = paging[1].text
# last_page = paging[len(paging) - 3].text

outfile = open('congregationlookup.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "Address", "Phone"])

pages = list(range(1, 1000))
for page in pages:

    url = 'https://urj.org/urj-congregations?congregation=&distance_address_field=&distance_num_miles=5.0&worship_services=All&community=All&urj_camp_affiliations=All&page=%s' % (
        page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    # print(soup.prettify())
    print('Processing page: %s' % (page))
    elements = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "views-row"})
    if len(elements) == 0:
        break
    for element in elements:
        name = element.find("div", {"class": "views-field views-field-congregation"}).text.strip()
        address = element.find("div", {"class": "views-field views-field-country"}).text.strip()
        phone = element.find("div", {"class": "views-field views-field-website"}).text.strip().split("\n")[0]
        writer.writerow([name, address, phone])

outfile.close()
print('Done')
```

Comment: Wow this worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help! The only issue now is that the loops stop at 9. So even though there are more pages, it doesn't capture them all.

Comment: That's because you are only capturing page numbers from first page

Comment: @Alex, i updated code, now it doesn't search for pagination, it just iterates until fails.

Comment: Upd: it parsed 821 rows. So i guess this is what you wanted)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your name_list contains a None type. So, when you attempt to run element.find(), you are performing a string operation on a None, hence your error.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Also as an FYI, findAll() is bs3 syntax. You should use find_all() [Difference between "findAll" and "find_all" in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339323/difference-between-findall-and-find-all-in-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

There is a load of problems

The first problem is

```
"pagination-heading--3"
```

istead of

```
"pagination-heading-3"
```

Next i changed

```
paging = soup.find("nav",{"aria-label":"pagination-heading-3"}).find("li",{"class":"page-item"}).find_all("a")
```

To

```
paging = soup.find("nav", {"aria-label": "pagination-heading--3"}).find("ul", {"class": "pagination"}).find_all("a")
```

This was the line where i swapped first problematic string. And also i changed the second search to find ul. You were trying to find 1 li and searching inside of it. This would have reproduced empty list
Next

```
last_page = paging[len(paging) - 3].text
```

as you are trying to get 3rd element from the end

It still doesn't work, i will keep updating

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the pagination issue. However, there are two issues with my scraping. First, it seems like I am only getting the first element of each page; that is, the first congregation on each page rather than all of the congregations on each page. I also, can't seem to get the address and phone number.

Comment: @Alex, added completed code. Ask anything if needed expalation